# Refreshing Listview's ArrayAdapter with the remove method throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I want to remove data from a `ListView`. For that on a long press event I've used the code below:

```
      lstGame.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FavouriteActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Remove from Favourite?").setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Const.favourite(FavouriteActivity.this, (args[arg2]));
                                Toast.makeText(FavouriteActivity.this, "Selected Item Removed from Favourite.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                // Here I get the UnsupportedException---->
                                // adapter.remove(args[arg2]);
                                lstGame.setAdapter(adapter);
                                lstGame.invalidate();

                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            Dialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Why do I get that exception?

Comment: please share the logcat logs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *adapter* reference points to a default `ArrayAdapter` instance then you most likely instantiate the `ArrayAdapter` using an `array` of objects as its source of data. If this is the case then, under the hood, the `ArrayAdapter` will transform that array into a special `ArrayList`(not the normal java one). This special `ArrayList` doesn't implement the methods that change its size(so using methods like `add` or `remove`(which modify that list) on the `ArrayAdapter` will throw the `UnsupportedOperationException`), it will only allow you to modify the values in it.

If you want to use that `remove` method then put the data from the `array` that you currently use in the `ArrayAdapter` in an `ArrayList` and then pass that list to the `ArrayAdapter` constructor.